# Failed to construct 'File': Iterator getter is not callable in chrome 60 when use JSON.stringify()

Tags: javascript, fileapi

System Configuration : macOS Sierra 10.12.5 ; chrome 60;

I am trying to download JSON data ( response object ) as a json file but when I tried to achive this using browser File() object , it gives error

`Failed to construct 'File': Iterator getter is not callable.`

below is my code

```
//`inputData` is the valid response getting from $http.get
var stringifyData = JSON.stringify(inputData);
console.log("stringifyData ", stringifyData);
var file = new File(blob, "filename.json", {type: "text/json;charset=utf-8"});
console.log("file", file);
```

what is the issue and why I am getting this error. when I use `JSON.stringify(inputData, undefined, 4);` then it gives no error and displays proper object in the console.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In your case `File` constructor signature is incorrect, the first argument must be:

> An Array of ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, or DOMString objects — or a mix of any such objects. This is the file content encoded as UTF-8.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File#Parameters

```
new File([blob], "filename.json", {type: "text/json;charset=utf-8"});
```

Comment: Looks like same applies to `new Blob(...)` as well. Thanks for the explicit example.

Comment: can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65541545/getting-failed-to-execute-createobjecturl-on-url-overload-resolution-failed

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late but I am facing the same issue so I thought should post my function it will help to convert BLOB to FILE.
Thanks

```
 imageCropped(event: ImageCroppedEvent) {
    this.Files = event.file;
    let fileName = new Date().getTime() + ".jpeg";
    let filedata = new File([this.Files], fileName, {
      type: "image/jpeg",
      lastModified: Date.now()
    });
    console.log(filedata);
  }
```